# how to convert multiple csv files to multiple tables in sqlite using python3?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, csv

I was trying to import multiple csv files into sqlite database into multiple tables(using jupyter notebook in python3). The name of each file will be the name of the table. I have defined a function to covert the encoding to utf8 as below:

```
import sqlite3
import glob
import csv
import sys
def convert_to_utf8(dirname):
    for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(dirname, '*.csv')):
        ifp = open(filename, "rt", encoding='cp1252')
        input_data = ifp.read()
        ifp.close()
        ofp = open(filename + ".fix", "wt", encoding='utf-8')
        for c in input_data:
            if c != '\0':
                ofp.write(c)
        ofp.close()
    return
```

all the files are in the same folder. staging_dir_name_1 is where the files are. And I have below code to covert the csv file into tables, some of the codes are from similar questions in StackFlow:

```
convert_to_utf8(staging_dir_name_1)
conn = sqlite3.connect("medicare_hospital_compare_1.db")
c = conn.cursor()
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(staging_dir_name_1, '*.csv')):
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        data = csv.DictReader(f)
        cols = data.fieldnames
        tablename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(filename))[0]

        sql_str = "drop table if exists %s" % tablename
        c.execute(sql_str)

        sql_str = "create table if not exists %s (%s)" % (tablename, ','.join(["%s text" % col for col in cols]))
        c.execute(sql_str)

        sql_str = "insert into %s values (%s)" % (tablename, ','.join(["?" for col in cols]))
        c.executemany(sql_str, (list(map(row.get, cols)) for row in data))

conn.commit()
```

but when i run this i get this error

```
> Error                                     Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-29-be7c1f43e4c5> in <module>()
>       2     with open(filename, "rb") as f:
>       3         data = csv.DictReader(f)
> ----> 4         cols = data.fieldnames
>       5         tablename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(filename))[0]
>       6 
> 
> C:\Users\dupin\Anaconda3\lib\csv.py in fieldnames(self)
>      96         if self._fieldnames is None:
>      97             try:
> ---> 98                 self._fieldnames = next(self.reader)
>      99             except StopIteration:
>     100                 pass
> 
> Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the
> file in text mode?)
```

Could anyone help me on how to resolve this issue? I have been thinking about it for a while but still couldn't figure out how to resolve this.

```
                             **===UPDATE===**
```

Now i have changed 'rb' to 'rt', i got a new error full NULL values, i think the first function has already removed all the null values

```
Error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-77-68d56c0b4cf2> in <module>()
      3 
      4         data = csv.DictReader(f)
----> 5         cols = data.fieldnames
      6         table = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(filename))[0]
      7 

C:\Users\dupin\Anaconda3\lib\csv.py in fieldnames(self)
     96         if self._fieldnames is None:
     97             try:
---> 98                 self._fieldnames = next(self.reader)
     99             except StopIteration:
    100                 pass

Error: line contains NULL byte
```

Comment: The error message suggests that you opened the file not in a text format. And, indeed, you seem to read it in binary: "with open(filename, "rb") as f:". So, maybe try to open it in text "rb"->"rt" for starters?

Comment: yeah i found this issue too and changed it. But got this error, I think i have already removed the null in the first step.

Comment: Did you check, what's written in the file? Maybe try to open it with any editor? Maybe your files, indeed, contain NULL bytes?